# Some doubts about using time random effect

Tags: r, random-effects-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

I'm starting with `lme4` and GLMM. Maybe this question can be basic for experimented researchers, but I'm still learning.

I have a pooled data where every observation is independent for every year. Will it be correct consider time random effect in a GLMM? Or maybe, Should I use other kind of models?

The model is specified as follow:

```
model <- glmer(response ~ V1 + V2 + (1|TIME), family = binomial, data =data))
```

Thanks for any help, references are welcome.

Comment: Could you give a more thorough description of data? In the question, you define a model where two observations from the same year (assuming TIME is year) are correlated, but observations from different years are not. Is this what you want? Your question is difficult to answer as it stands.

Comment: Exactly, observations from the same year (assuming TIME is year) are correlated, but observations from different years are not.